# boxplot: argument "x" is missing, with no default

Tags: r, boxplot

I try to create a boxplot with a logarithmic scale, but this code:

```
data <- t(read.csv(file=args[1], header=FALSE, sep=";"))

boxplot(data = data, log = "y")
```

causes this error:

```
Warning message:
In read.table(file = file, header = header, sep = sep, quote = quote,  :
  incomplete final line found by readTableHeader on 'complex_complexNormal.csv'
Error in split(x, rep.int(1L:ncol(x), rep.int(nrow(x), ncol(x)))) : 
  argument "x" is missing, with no default
Calls: boxplot -> boxplot.matrix -> split
```

I can't figure out where this error come from.

Comment: Try `boxplot(data, log = "y")`.

Comment: Try specifying the `formula` argument - see `?boxplot`.

Comment: There is no `data` argument in the S3 `boxplot` method.  There is one in the `formula` method. So one of the above comments will get 'er done.

Comment: Define a Formula like in `boxplot(count+10 ~ spray, data = InsectSprays, log="y")` which works